# Not inserting values in MySQL Table

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

We have two IR sensors interfaced with our RPi3, and we want to store the sensor data into the database.
This is the code we are trying to run.

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","Keerti","Keerti","test")

curs = db.cursor()

try:
    print "module test"
    time.sleep(2)
    print "ready"
while True:
    if GPIO.input(4):
        print "motion detected 1"
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO parktest(irname,irdata) VALUES('%f', '%f')" % (1,1))
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print "no motion 1"
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO parktest(irname,irdata) VALUES('%f', '%f')" % (1,0))
    time.sleep(1)
    if GPIO.input(14):
        print "motion detected 2"
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO parktest(irname, irdata) VALUES('%f','%f')" % (2,1))
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print "no motion 2"
        curs.execute("INSERT INTO parktest(irname, irdata) VALUES('%f','%f')" % (2,0))
    time.sleep(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "quit"
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This, runs fine without any warnings or errors. However, it isn't storing anything in the table.

What might be the issue?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This can't be the one you use.

Answer (score 0):

After ***execute()***, you must use [commit()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-commit.html) to confirm all the pending changes.

Or you can use [rollback()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-rollback.html) to cancel all the pendings.

Otherwise, nothing will be changed in database.